# is it possible to indicate a flag to include an audio files directory in Makefile for gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I would like to know if it's possible to indicate for gcc some flag that include a directory for different kind of files, like .wav or .txt. Then in my code I wouldn't need to indicate the directory to read the file.

Comment: Pass it as a macro on the compile line with -D?

Comment: Not clear what you want to accomplish. gcc is a compiler (frontend), it needs a specific input format. I don't think it will be able to play audio-files.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a macro on the compile line, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define qstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

int main(void)
{
    printf("The path is %s\n", qstr(MY_FILE_PATH));
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile as:

```
gcc -DMY_FILE_PATH="`pwd`/mymediadir/mywavfilesdir" test.c -o test
```

When run gives:

```
./test
The path is /home/joe/tmp/mymediadir/mywavfilesdir
```

Comment: Note that won't work: first nothing will expand `~` here and second you need to escape the quotes so they appear in the value of `MY_FILE_PATH`.